# how to domain one2many field from another function field in odoo 8?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-8

i want to filter get_parts_locations_rel_ids based on location_id in get_loc_user field... but i can't get it.

i used odoo 8 with old api

```
# this is my python code


_columns = {
        'get_loc_user': fields.function(check_location_user, string="loc_user", type="char"),
        'get_parts_locations_rel_ids': fields.one2many('parts.locations_rel','product_id','Locations'),
    }

# field 'get_loc_user' is a function that will return a list result such [1,2,3]

#-------------------------------

# in xml

<record id="product_normal_form_view_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.product.form</field>
            <field name="model">product.product</field>
            <field name="mode">primary</field>
            <field eval="7" name="priority"/>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="product.product_template_form_view"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='categ_id']" position="after">
                    <field name="get_loc_user"  />
                </xpath>
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='asset_ids']" position="after">
                    <field name="get_parts_locations_rel_ids">
                        <tree string="Locations" >
                            <field name="loc_case"/>
                            <field name="loc_row" />
                            <field name="loc_rack" />
                            <field name="location_id" />
                        </tree >
                    </field>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

i expect the result in one2many field get_parts_locations_rel_ids is filtering by field location_id based on get_loc_user field, but i don't know how to do that

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a domain for `get_loc_user` you can access it in `tree & form view` like this `parent.get_loc_user`

```xml
 <field name="location_id" domain="parent.get_loc_user and [('your_field_domain', '=', parent.get_loc_user)] or []"/>
```

I don't know what  you need exactly but I think you get the idea

Comment: thanks for the idea... but what is parent? do i must write parent or the parent form or tree or model or what? thanks before... sorry for my bad english and im a newbie in odoo...

Comment: no you don't have to declare it, it come out of the box from Odoo it's an easy way to access the field of the main model from the One2many field (in tree view). like in your case I don't know what you need exactly in your domain.

Comment: exactly i wanna domain a one2many field... exactly the same case like in the blog i find in google http://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2018/01/get-parent-form-value-in-one2many-form.html i try to follow the tutorial but i still can't get it... and sorry sir i wanna ask 1 thing again... which one is correct domain="[('field_name', 'in', (1,2,3))]" or domain="[('field_name', 'in', [1,2,3] )]"? which one is correct use tuple or list? thanks before sir...

Comment: Both work fine but I by habit I use list so I don't get confused with a lot of parentheses ^^.